# How to pass cloud-init file locally?

Tags: azure, cloud-init

I have been working on windows bash and tried to pass the cloud init file, unfortunately i can not access the app through web, 
below is the reference..

"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-automate-vm-deployment"

Comment: @Pradeep thanks, i am on windows  bash system, when i checked my cloud_init.txt file  i got below  
 neo@dcadmin:/mnt/c/Users/dcadmin$ ls -lrth | grep cloud_init.txt
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Application Data': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Cookies': Permission denied
ls: cannot read symbolic link 'Local Settings': Permission denied
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1.1K May 21 11:08 cloud_init.txt

Comment: @Pradeep Thanks, i believe that i was on path /mnt/c/user/dcadmin which could be causing the problem, i had changed to /home/user created the cloud-init file and it worked.

Comment: now the problem seems to have ssh access to the server "Resource temporarily unavailable"  debug1: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any editor you wish from “[Linux text editors](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/top-5-best-linux-text-editors/)” to create cloud-init.txt file locally.

I used nano editor to **create cloud-init.txt** file as follows:

**nano cloud-init.txt**

Copy and paste content mentioned in the document mentioned.

**Ctrl+X** to save and press **Y**;

[image]

Now use az login to sign-in, if you have not install azure cli 2.0 you may refer “[Install Azure CLI 2.0 with apt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest)”.

**az login**

[image]

Now create a VM with –custom-data as follows:

```
az vm create --resource-group myResourceGroupAutomate --name myVM --image UbuntuLTS --admin-username azureuser --generate-ssh-keys  --custom-data /root/cloud-init.txt
```

[image]

To allow web traffic to reach your VM, open port 80 from the Internet with az vm open-port:

```
az vm open-port --port 80 --resource-group myResourceGroupAutomate --name MyVM
```

**Test web app**:

[image]